# Escaping reference to local variable

Tags: d

I am new to the D language. While trying to create a simple function that returns a byte array, I run into errors when trying to return my value. Is there a different way I am supposed to return a local variable from a function?

On the the return line, I get error `Error: escaping reference to local c`

My code:

```d
byte[] xorFixed(byte[] a, byte[] b){
   if (a.sizeof != b.sizeof) return null;
   byte[a.sizeof] c;
   for (int i = 0; i < a.sizeof; i++)
   {
      c[i] = (a[i] ^ b[i]);

   return c;
}
```

Comment: `.sizeof`? Maybe you meant `.length`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`byte[]` and `byte[some_size]` are two different types. A `byte[some_size]` is a static array that is copied around when used and a `byte[]` is a slice or dynamic array that points to its values.

When you try to `return c`, since the return value is a slice, it tries to take a pointer to `c`... which is a local value that ceases to exist when the function returned. If this compiled, it would give you gibberish or a crash at runtime!

You need to fix the type. `c` should *not* be `byte[a.sizeof]`. It should just be a plain `byte[]`. To set the size of an array, use `.length` instead of `.sizeof`.

```d
if (a.length != b.length) return null; // changed sizeof -> length
byte[] c; // changed type
c.length = a.length; // this sets the length of c to match a
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) // changed sizeof to length
```

That will do what you want.

Comment: Another alternative is to change the function to have a return type of `auto` and it'll infer `byte[a.sizeof]` as the return type instead of `byte[]`.

Comment: `a.sizeof` is wrong though, it isn't the same thing as length.

Answer (score 4):

An example of more idiomatic D code:

```d
ubyte[] xor(in ubyte[] a, in ubyte[] b)
{
    assert(a.length == b.length);

    auto c = new ubyte[a.length];

    return c[] = a[] ^ b[];
}
```